# Hello I am the beginner to laravel , I don't know how to start and run my first program kindly anyone can help me

Tags: laravel-5

Hello I am the beginner to Laravel , I don't know  how to start and run my first program kindly anyone can help me

Comment: For any programming framework/language/tool, the first sample is almost always to get the system to display/print/sing "hello world". Have you *searched for* and followed *any* tutorial you might find by searching for `laravel hello world`?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but SO is not a place to ask how to start a project. SO is a place to answer problems you have with code. If you want to start with Laravel I recommend reading some tutorials or watch some videos on youtube.

Comment: Have you check the doc? (https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of useful information like video courses, forum here: https://laracasts.com/

Or you can watch the laravel series on youtube from [DevMarketer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6kwT7-jjZHHF1s7vCfg2CA)

And you can always check the official documentation of Laravel [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/).

Answer (score 0):

Read full official documentation of laravel framework

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/readme

Answer (score 0):

Follow this, has all the info for beginners
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Follow following Urls that will help you to study laravel step by step
https://laravel-news.com/your-first-laravel-application
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6